# If I am using DRY lube, do I need to clean my chain between applications?

Tags: maintenance, chain, cleaning

Do I need to clean the chain before reapplying dry lube if I am only using dry lube?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I read it in the context of advice that chain lube ought never be applied on a dirty chain since it may carry grit into the bushings. This advice usually is given with regard to use of regular chain lube (wet lube). The best answer so far, Criggie's, is still a bit vague in that regard.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should clean the chain occasionally.  Where does the dirt go if you don't clean it off ?

True that dry lubricants are not as sticky as wet ones, but there's still dirt there and it needs to come off, not get further into your chain's gubbins.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do a quick "Wipe down with an oily rag" after anything more than a quick ride to the shops. It does help but I will get the chain off and give it a full valet job every couple of months, more often in the winter.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question - no, you do not need to clean the chain between every lube. You do need to clean the chain regularly.

Follow the manufacturer's instructions.  Some dry lubes are a cleaner - you apply heaps, and it washes the chain, wipe dry then maybe apply more - what made it to the rollers lubes the chain. A light application of this type should not be considered a clean. Others dry lubes are thicker and cannot be used this way.

The 'clean and lube in one' approach (presuming it works) has an advantage that its quick, easy and hard to get wrong but is probably more expensive.  The convivence is great when on road trips with the bike and would work for someone without 'workshop' space for looking after their bike. Cleaning then lubing in two separate steps requires two products, tends to take longer, can be a bit messier but is likely cheaper and more effective at keeping a chain clean.

The debates on chain lubing, how often, what brand, what type and cleaning - how and how often with what cleaner are bordering on religious on their own. Combining them is fraught and it is a brave or foolish person to enter the debate :)

My advice (I must be a fool :) ) is do what works for you. Too much cleaning and lubing is a waste of time and money on lube, to little is a waste of a good chain (time and money) and may cassettes. The sweat spot depends on how much you value your time and your money. It's very easy to spend more on cleaners and lubes than they save in chain wear, but it is also easy to do an adequate job cheaply.

Comment: That makes sense, I also started using dry lube recently and I've noticed that while the drivetrain often looks pristine when riding in dry on-roads conditions, even after 200k, lube wears off anyway and there is (a bit) more noise then on a freshly lubed chain (as an indicator). So you, should keep track of proper lubrication intervals and have yourself guided a little less by visible dirt. Always lubricate, clean when needed - that's not so much the case with oil because the drivetrain picks up dirt like free beer in any case. 

Answer (score -1):

Yes. We should clean our chains regularly irrespective of the type of lube.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17680)

Comment: @BenediktBauer you must be reading a different question than I am. Or you are reading a different answer. Or you are commenting on the wrong answer. Whatever the case, you are completely wrong.

Comment: I have to agree, this is an answer, even though it is a short one without an explanation.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Nice!